# No Wifi connection on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, networking, iwlwifi

since I bought my new laptop, with a wifi card Intel Wireless AC 9260, I cannot connect to any wireless network. When I choose the network to connect it tries to but at the end it displays a behavior like timeout connection. Any of you face a similar problem before? (Yes, I already did extensive searches looking for related problems but any solution worked).

Ps.: the wifi connection works fine in Windows.

---

Exit lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 3ec2 (rev 07)    
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Gaussian Mixture Model
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device a2af
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device a2b1
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device a2ba
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device a282
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a290 (rev f0)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a296 (rev f0)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a297 (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a298 (rev f0)
00:1d.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a29c (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device a2c9
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Device a2a1
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device a2f0
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device a2a3
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1be0 (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 10f0 (rev a1)
6d:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros Device e0b1 (rev 10)
6e:00.0 SD Host controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5250 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
**70:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 2526 (rev 29)**
```

---

EDIT 1:

output lspci -k

```
70:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 2526 (rev 29)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 0014
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

output uname -r

```
4.13.0-45-generic
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try just to upgrade to a new stable kernel (assumimg you are on x86_64):

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.17.8/

Make a new dir, then download there linux amd64: headers all, headers generic, image generic and modules generic deb packages, then cd to created directory and install all of them using

```
sudo dpkg -i *
```

Then do

```
sudo update-grub
```

And reboot your laptop with a new kernel. This must help.

Comment: Yes, with the new kernel update (made available today for 16.04) it worked. Thanks.